# Column in DataFrame in Pandas with value 0

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, transform

I try to create 2 new columns in DataFrame in Pandas Python and the first column `aa` which shows average temperaturę is correct, nevertheless, the second column `bb` which should present temperature in City minus average temperature in all cities displays value `0`??

Where is the problem? Did I correctly use lambda? Could you give me the solution? Thank you very much!

```
file["aa"] = file.groupby(['City'])["Temperature"].transform(np.mean)
display(file.sample(10))

file["bb"] = file.groupby(['City'])["Temperature"].transform(lambda x: x - np.mean(x))
display(file.head(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Updated according to [gereleth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7746385/gereleth)'s comment. You can simplify it even more!

```
file['bb'] = file.Temperature - file.aa
```

Since we've already calculated the mean value in the `aa` column we can simply reuse this column to calculate the difference of the `Temperature` and `aa` column of each row by using pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method like below:

```
file["aa"] = file.groupby(['City'])["Temperature"].transform(np.mean)
display(file.sample(10))
file["bb"] = file.apply(lambda row: row['Temperature'] - row['aa'], axis=1)
display(file.sample(10))
```

If you are looking to subtract the average of all cities temperature you can use mean on the column `aa` instead:

```
file["aa"] = file.groupby(['City'])["Temperature"].transform(np.mean)
display(file.sample(10))
avg_all_cities = file['aa'].mean()
file["bb"] = file.apply(lambda row: row['Temperature'] - avg_all_cities, axis=1)
display(file.sample(10))
```

Comment: why apply a lambda when you could just write `file.Temperature - file.aa`?..

Comment: Ya, that should also work. Updated my answer. Thanks!